# Why is two way send port not processing response?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

We have a two-way receive port 'ReceivePort1', receiving message type of MessageA.

A two-way send port 'SendPort1' subscribes to MessageA and sends it to a rest service 'MyRestService'.

The rest service returns a response of message type MessageB, with an element that gets promoted as 'PropertyA' with a value of '1'

A two-way send port 'SendPort2' subscribes to MessageB with PropertyA=1 and sends it to the same rest service 'MyRestService'.

The rest service returns a response of message type MessageB, with an element that gets promoted as 'PropertyA' with a value of '2'

A one way send port 'SendPort3' subscribes to MessageB with Property=2 and sends via SMPT.

Essentially, the flow is ReceivePort1 -> SendPort1 -> SendPort2 -> SendPort3.

The issue is that the response received by SendPort2 is never consumed by BizTalk.  Using fiddler we can see that the service returns the response, but we have no tracking information, no message, no event log error to signify that BizTalk ever saw it.  We've even tried to debug the receive pipeline on the send port and the pipeline is never passed the response message.  We've tried using passthrough, xmlreceive, and our own custom pipeline in the receive pipeline of SendPort2, neither seem to be passed the response from the rest service.  Is the chain of two way send ports meaningful here?  Is BizTalk doing something I am not aware of?

**Edit 1:**

As a test,  I simplified the scenario, and SendPort3 receives a file from a one way file receive port, and it worked.  The receive pipeline on the file port is the same receive pipeline as on Sendport2.  Next test is to have SendPort2 receive a file from a one way file receive port.

**Edit 2:**

SendPort2 receiving a file from one way file receive and everything works. We have found that in the original scenario of Two Way ReceivePort1 -> Two Way SendPort1 -> Response -> Two Way SendPort2 -> Response -> SendPort3, when we inspect the pipeline for the request side of SendPort3  the IsSolicitResponse context property is false.  This property instructs the wcf adaptor to either expect a response back or not.  We don't yet know where in the chain the IsSolicitResponse is getting set to false.

Comment: A bit hard to diagnose what the issue is with what you have given.  Have you tried a simpler scenario where SendPort2 receives a message from a one way receive location?   What is the Http status code that you get from the service?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf - I agree, but that's the scenario that we have having trouble with.  I'll try this all from a 1 way receive port